# In Thomas Hardy’s “Far From the Madding Crowd,” what is the significance of Bathsheba’s equestrian skills at the beginning of the novel?

Tags: thomas-hardy, far-from-the-madding-crowd

Early in Chapter 2 of the novel, Gabriel watches Bathsheba without being observed. Bathsheba is riding a horse and comes to a low branch.  She looks around to see if there is anyone about, not seeing Gabriel she then acrobatically lies back on the horse to pass under the branch, then snaps  to new position and finally jumps into a straddle ride as opposed to side saddle.  Gabriel is amazed by this ability and notes she “can ride a horse from head to tail.”

This ability is then never explained or ever even mentioned again?  It is a bit like placing a loaded gun on stage in act one and then never referring to it again?

I understand that her movement from side saddle to straddle foreshadows she can and will later fill the role of a man (leading a farm) and has a number of sexual connotations and that she is watched by Gabriel in secret just like the original Bathsheba was by David - but what is the purpose of the suggestion she is a trained equestrian/stunt rider?

Comment: Remember this was serialized.  He might have meant to do something with it, and then decided against it when it was too late to revise an already published installment.

Comment: Maybe. But he revised the book in later years.  
Someone pointed out that it had some sexual connotations to it - nubile girl maneuvering around the horse and then riding astride the horse as opposed to side saddle ( which was considered improper for a women).

Comment: It's an admirable skill. It's like observing that she's smart as well as hot.

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that Bathsheba's saddleback manouvres take place in chapter 3 (not 2 ).